# Wood rot underneath window in a 2in window sill

Tags: windows, exterior, rot

Underneath my window, there is a large sill that angles downward. On the right side there appears to be quite a lot of rot, see attached image. The pliers are about 2 inches long and are penetrating horizontally underneath the trim on the right side of the window.

I am assuming this rot has come from the vinyl window being improperly installed. I am comfortable addressing the rot in the wood, but I have been unable to find a diagram of how the window might be framed above this sill, so I am hesitant to start digging.

Do you know of how best to address this rot? Any diagram showing how the window might be in there, and how the sill might sit would be very appreciated.

[image: frame rot in lower right of window]

Comment: If that is on the outside of the structure, (as it looks), if the wood is not caulked and repainted on a  yearly basis, it will rot.  Not likely the result of poor installation, but poor selection of products.   The framing of the window can be done in a number of different ways depending on the windows being flanged, or unflanged.  You need to remove the trim and take a look,

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense! This is my first house, and it is very old without someone loving it for a long time. 

I guess what I am having trouble wrapping my head around is if that horizontal piece that is rotten goes completely under the vinyl window, or if it just is on the outside of the house, attached outside the frame of the window. Is there anyway to tell without starting to remove trim?

Comment: sorry it will require exploratory surgery.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the input! Do you have any recommendations on how to winterize this? Or should I just get on with it? Where I live it gets quite rainy over the winter months.

Comment: There is no advantage to waiting...get on with it.